# "{which/which language} I can't understand"

Tags: relative-pronouns

1. > He sometimes speaks Spanish, which I can't understand.
2. > He sometimes speaks Spanish, which language I can't understand.

Which sentence is correct? Or are all of them possible?

How about the following:

3. > He sometimes speaks **in Spanish**, which I can't understand.
4. > He sometimes speaks **in Spanish**, which language I can't understand.

Comment: Either one. The first one sounds more natural to me (native speaker).

Comment: The second one definitely DOES NOT sound natural to this native US English speaker.  It might be technically correct in a formal sense, but it is not common usage.

Comment: Agree with stangdon about U.S. usage.

Answer (score 2):

The form A is the preferred one:

> He sometimes speaks Spanish, which I can't understand.

The part of the sentence that follows the comma is a relative clause, connected to the *noun* "Spanish".  In that clause "*I*" is the subject "*can't understand*" is the predicate.  The **object** of that clause is actually "*Spanish*" represented by the relative pronoun "*which*".  The pronoun migrates to the beginning of the clause and retains the status of the object.

If we split the sentence into two, we get

> He sometimes speaks Spanish.  I can't understand Spanish.

Now, why does "which language" sound awkward?  Simply put, **because it would be *redundant***.  The word "Spanish" in the main clause *already has the meaning* "**language**".  It's does *not* mean "architecture" or "history", so there is no need to repeat it.

---

As far as "speaks ***in*** Spanish" versus "speaks Spanish", there is no difference.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the first form is the correct one:

> He sometimes speaks Spanish, which I can't understand.

You could make the second one acceptable by changing the word *which* to the indefinite article *a*:

> He sometimes speaks Spanish, <strike>which language I can't understand</strike>.
> He sometimes speaks Spanish, **a** language I can't understand.

I concur with Victor that the *in* is optional in both cases, with little difference in the overall meaning:

> He sometimes speaks **in** Spanish, a language I can't understand.

However, this is true for the verb *speaks*. If we swap out the verb *speak* for another verb, then the *in* might become mandatory:

> He sometimes says words **in** Spanish, which I can't understand.
> <strike>He sometimes says words Spanish, which I can't understand</strike>.
>
> He sometimes orates **in** Spanish, a language I can't understand.
> <strike>He sometimes orates Spanish, a language I can't understand</strike>.

Moreover, sometimes the preposition could be included or omitted, depending on what you are trying to say; for example:

> He sometimes narrates Spanish, a language I don't understand.
> He sometimes narrates **in** Spanish, a language I don't understand.

I'd be more inclined to use the first one if he is narrating from a Spanish text, but more inclined to use the second one if he is translating English on the fly and thus narrating in Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

In your sentence, the first option sounds more natural and is more common.

However there are times when specifying a noun after *which* can add clarification and thus be natural.

Let's take the following example, using a language other than Spanish.

> He sometimes speaks in an assortment of grimaces and grunts and whistles, accompanied by stares, winks and gestures, which language I don't understand.

Or consider this example:

> He sometimes speaks Spanish, not the Spanish of Mexico City or the Spanish of Madrird, not even the Spanish of Barcelona, but the Spanish of the aboriginal peoples of Brazil, which language I don't understand.

In fact, it would also be common to use *Spanish* once again instead of *language*:

> He sometimes speaks Spanish, not the Spanish of Mexico City or the Spanish of Madrird, not even the Spanish of Barcelona, but the Spanish of the aboriginal peoples of Brazil, which Spanish I don't understand.